# How to access Isolated scope API fields when dealing with `Controller As` syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code  which allows to select a place from Google maps.

When you select a place , it shows you what you've selected and its LAT/LON :

[image]

You can see it [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpxQM0ZKeoSjLf9qvoli?p=preview)

But that code is *not* using the `controller as` syntax.

So I've changed it:

- Controller change :

[image: in the html :]

- Html change :

[image]

- Directive change:

[image]

Here is the NEW [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/jujc3o3TaDLmzShX84V6?p=preview)

But now when I select a place - it doesn't update the values.

**Question**

How can I fix my code so that it will still interact via :

```
scope: {
        details: '=',
        ngAutocomplete: '=',
        options: '=',
        lt:'=',
        ln:'=',
      }
```

(When I move to `controller as`)

I mean  - shouldn't I use the `controller` ( not the `scope`) in :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) ??
```

What am I missing ?

If they say that now (*"controller as" syntax*) the controller is our viewModel so I don't see anything wrong with using the controller parameter and access :

```
controller.lt = ...;
controller.ln = ...;
```

And I'm obviously wrong here ...

Comment: you missing that link `scope` but use `controller`

Comment: @Grundy I don't get your point.Can you elaborate ?

Comment: you pass into directive: `scope.lt, scope.ln` that refers to `controler.lat, controler.long`  but inside directly set `controller.lt`, `controller.lg` so your `controller.lat` stil undefined

Comment: Also `controller` that passed to _link_ function not same instance as controller that in view

Comment: @Grundy So how would you refer to `controller.lat` from your directive ?

Comment: you can't, just by scope. You can avoid usnig _scope_ only use some factory or service that inject in controller

Comment: @Grundy So what the hell is going on here? Controller has no scope . And from the directive you set (via isolated scope) the parent scope(?!!?) values ? but there is no scope in parent due to `controller as` ! .There is only `new Controller()` instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93858/discussion-between-grundy-and-royi-namir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be jumbling up a few concepts because you're trying to use the same controller both in your directive and outside it.

Even if you're using `controller As` outside your directive, the implementation inside your directive should stay the same. The whole point is that the directive should not care what's going on outside of it. The `scope: {}` option allows you to tell the directive which values to put on its own scope, based on the attribute values provided.

So the answer is to leave your directive code unchanged from your original example, and everything will work.

Working plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xyTX95JA2biYJmWPKxzZ?p=preview

Side note: You should avoid prefixing your components with `ng`. The `ng` prefix is intended for components that are built into Angular, and you should use your own prefix.

Comment: My thoughts were that NG doesn't concern anymore about scope , and now the viewmodel is the `new Controller()` thing. And so I thought that the directive should have access to that INSTANCE of the `new Controller()`....no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, the directive should not be directly accessing the controller outside it. The directive has its own scope. That's why the option is called `scope`.

Comment: So for the directive there **is** a `scope` (isolated one) but for the controller there is **no** scope but `new controller()` due to `controller as` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, I would say that's pretty much correct.

Comment: They could have built it better. Too many ways to get lost. This is not how Framework should be written. (BTW thank you)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using $scope.$watch();

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return vm.location_result;
}, function(location) {
    if (location) {
       // do something
    }
});
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n3ztwucL/

GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/robrothedev/46e1b2a2470b1f8687ad